# Laravel 8 - GET http://localhost:8000/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel

I can't use the `app.css` in my application. Every time the server returns following error

> GET http://localhost:8000/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

I use a blade page.

```html
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I tried to use `php artisan serve` and `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` and the booth didn't work.

Comment: My code is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <body>
        <section id="conteudo-view" class=login>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'user.login', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
        <p>Acesse o Sistema</p>        

        <label>
        </label>

        <label>
        </label>
        
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Where is `css/app.css` is placed?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\css

Comment: css and  js files must be in public  folder ...

Comment: Did you actually compile your assets? `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`? [The manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix)

Comment: it's works. I copy the app.css to the public folder. Thanks a lot  @dılosürücü

Answer (score 7):

try this before running your project on server make sure to compile laravel-mix

```
npm install
```

and then run

```
npm run dev
```

your facing the error because app.css not compiled yet

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile your css imports properly in `resources/css/app.css` first. It should look something like this:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Bootstrap
@import 'bootstrap';

// Font Awesome
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';
```

Then, run this on your terminal: `npm run dev`. This will in turn, compile your `app.css` in your `public/css`. If you are making custom css definitions, i suggest using a `custom.css` and putting it in your `public/css` folder, and define it BELOW your `app.css`, like:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Assets must always be in the `public` folder so they can be seen by the `{{asset ('') }}` command.

Answer (score -1):

Use this worked 100%

run this command

```
npm i vue-loader
```

then run

```
npm run dev
```

you will get your solution .

Answer (score -1):

This the step for **installing**:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui bootstrap

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install
```

npm run dev

If you get an error at this step you can try this:

`npm run prod` or `npm run production`